# Force external links (from my website) to open in a new tab within the default browser for that device?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

if I have a mobile-friendly website (not an App). Is it possible to force external links to Facebook or Instagram or any other App (that uses WebView) to open in the default browser for that device?

I'd like the user experience on mobile to be as close as possible to the desktop experience. But certain apps hijack the links. And the user isn't always deposited on the appropriate destination page in that app's Webview. Instead, they sometimes land on an "upgrade" or "offer" page for that App - with no way to navigate to the intended destination.

Again - my own platform isn't a mobile app. It's a angularjs and php mobile-friendly webpage within the default browser for the device.

Is there any code I can insert (either globally or around each individual link) to force external links (from my website) to open in a new tab within the default browser for that device?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: thats not possible. If another website does something like offer an *upgrade* there is nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

In Facebook case, we can use `fb://` directly

```
<a href="fb://link.com/" rel="alternate" target="_blank" />
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't need for the only facebook. LinkedIn and Instagram etc